# Simple, free PDF editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, pdf-editor

Does anyone know of a simple, free PDF editor for Windows?

When I search, I find a lot of deceptive sites that say it's free but then there are 10 ads that look like download buttons and a virus inside.

I don't need fancy features, just editing text pretty much. Maybe inserting images as well. I'm sure someone has written a free (maybe even open source) PDF editor. It's just impossible to find it.

Can anyone recommend good software for this?

Answer (score 5):

For interactive pdf **editing** I would suggest installing [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/) which can edit *most* pdf files and write pdf files.

Note that pdf files from some sources, such as most scanners and some software, do not contain any text and instead contain either images of each page, the vectors to draw the text, or more than one of these - such files are never going to be **simple** to edit because you will have to edit them as images - however if a file looks unlike the expected page in LibreOffice Writer *(the word processor)* try LibreOffice Draw *(the drawing package)* which will open the document as a drawing.

If you are looking to simplify the **producing** of pdf files then I would suggest using the [python](http://python.org) [rst2pdf](http://rst2pdf.ralsina.me/stories/index.html) tool where you write your document in [reStructuredText](http://rst2pdf.ralsina.me/stories/quickstart.html) and then pop it through the tool to produce your pdf.

Both the above are:

1. Free, Gratis & Open Source
2. Multi-platform running on at least *all current versions of* Windows, OS/X & Linux.

Comment: I meant, even if you _try_ to open it with LO Draw it might still bring up Writer.

Answer (score 1):

**Disclosure: I'm a founder of DeftPDF.**

I understand your frustration in trying to find a reliable, free PDF editor for Windows. Luckily, I have a recommendation that I think you'll find helpful. Have you tried [Deftpdf](https://deftpdf.com/)? It's an online PDF editor that offers a wide range of features and tools for editing PDF files, and the best part is that it's completely free and without any ads.

With Deftpdf, you can easily edit existing text in your PDF documents and insert images as well. In fact, Deftpdf offers over 40 different tools for working with PDFs, including features for merging, splitting, and converting files.

One of the great things about Deftpdf is that you don't have to download any software or worry about viruses, since it's an online tool.

Comment: You could improve it by describing its features in a list.

Comment: Sorry but this tool gives me a different file after every save. First, vertical text becomes horizontal, so I remove it. Then some accented letters disappear, and then I add letters without accents instead, the filling of pictures changes to black.

Comment: can you please submit the bug with the link below and upload the file you trying to process ?   https://forms.clickup.com/2232085/f/243rn-16505/4NFKC6XP8C352JDFUJ