# Simple, free PDF meta tag editor for Windows?

Tags: windows, gratis, pdf, metadata-editor, metadata

Does anyone know a simple, free PDF meta tag editor for Windows?

When I google, I find a lot of deceptive sites that say it's free but then there are 10 ads that look like download buttons and a virus inside.

I don't need fancy features, just editing meta info - author, description, copyright, etc. Ideally if it works from command line.

Can anyone recommend good software for this?

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [PDF-XChange Viewer](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads) for this task.

It is a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) (no cost) [pdf-viewer](/questions/tagged/pdf-viewer) for [windows](/questions/tagged/windows) that also happens to include extensive [metadata-editor](/questions/tagged/metadata-editor) functionality.

It has no ads for third-party programs.  It does have a *tiny* static promo for their PDF Creation Tools program, but it is hardly noticeable.  There is nothing deceptive in the program at all, and my experience is that the company that develops this software is very reputable.

The [downloads page](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads) includes a link to download a [portable](/questions/tagged/portable) version that does not require any installer.

To edit [metadata](/questions/tagged/metadata), simply go the **File** menu and select **Document Properties** (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>).  A dialog box will pop up in which you can edit the [metadata](/questions/tagged/metadata).  There is even an **Additional Metadata** button in that dialog box that will allow you to quickly edit the Document Title, Author, Author Title, Description, Description Writer, Keywords, Copyright Status, Copyright Notice, and the Copyright Info URL tags.  It's quite impressive.

[image]

I have successfully used this application many times, and I can recommend it as a high quality piece of software.

---

Update: As illustrated by the screenshot above, this program unfortunately cannot modify either the created or modified metadata timestamps stored within PDF files. Still an issue almost 7 years later.

Comment: Apparently "Viewer" is discontinued, now merged with or replaced by "Editor" (version 6.0.317 as I write this). From what I can tell after using it for a few minutes, it is indeed a capable and polished product. Honestly, I can't even find the "tiny static" self-promotion you're talking about; maybe they got rid of it. The "About" pop-up in the Help menu says the program is free for both private and commercial use, and only additional advanced features require payment. Really, the only "problem" is that, given OP's requirements, this program is too much, and not suitable for the command line.

Comment: Maybe this would be a better fit for OP's [other, very similar question](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26788/simple-free-pdf-editor-for-windows).

Comment: @JohnY Yes, the author recently superseded the Viewer product with their Editor product.  The Editor product does not even have that tiny promotion (as of this posting).  The Viewer product is now available from the author here: https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads/discontinued

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're actually looking for, as your post on SU and other post here are asking for a text editor.  Since here you are asking for a metadata editor, have a look at this.  It appears to allow you to edit what you're trying to change.

http://broken-by.me/pdf-metadata-editor/

Answer (score 0):

The pdf toolkit, [pdftk](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/), can perform a huge number of operations, on pdf files including `update_info` which is what I think you are looking for:

1. Command Line or batch file use
2. Free/Gratis for the command line/server version,
3. Can dump meta data, can change meta data, can watermark, split, merge, etc.
4. GUI/Pro Edition, (also provides server edition), is very cheap < $5.
5. No Ads/Spyware/etc.