# A PDF editor for Linux

Tags: gratis, linux, pdf, pdf-editor

I would like to add some text and an image to some PDF files − nothing complicated, but apparently software to do this is difficult to find :-/

I tried:

- LibreOffice, but that mangles some PDF documents in ways that I've seen no other program do.
- Inkscape doesn't work well with multi-paged documents.
- PDFedit is based on Qt3, I might be able to get it running by compiling the old Qt3 stuff, but I'd rather not go down that road... I tried the Windows build with wine but that doesn't seem to work (lots of errors, crash).

Open source is preferred, but not required. I don't even mind running Wine ([Simple, free PDF editor for Windows?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/26788/9025) doesn't list any other alternatives though). Watermarks and such are not acceptable.

Comment: What do you want to edit? Where do the PDF come from (which version of PDF)

Comment: In my experience, crashes in PDFedit happen when it misdetects fonts (or something). If I use "select font from page" it's all fine. I would also recommend [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162037/how-to-edit-pdfs) btw.

Comment: This is *almost* a duplicate of ["PDF editor for Linux"](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35900/pdf-editor-for-linux).

Answer (score 1):

There's a number of pieces of PDF software for Linux but the Open Source software tend to be outdated in comparison to the commercial software.

Open Source you've got:

- pdftk
- qpdf
- Scribus
- GIMP
- PDFEdit

I wouldn't use Wine for PDF editing as the lack of dependencies (and even the .NET framework) can cause you real problems. If you don't mind out-of-date software then PDFEdit is powerful enough for most people.

**However if you want up-to-date, commercial software then I'd recommend [PDF Studio by Qoppa](https://www.qoppa.com/pdfstudio/).**

You get all the normal functionality including the ability to make/edit PDF's, create/complete forms, encryption/protection, digitally sign, watermark, OCR, editable text, redaction, optimisation, convert to raster, redaction, linearize, convert to HTML5/SVG, bookmarks etc.

So far it has been the only one which receives regular updates, supports AES-256 on Linux and has a decent GUI. The problem with other Linux software is they're either no longer supported or they provide minimal functionality.

It comes in two editions: Standard and Pro and is considerably cheaper than Adobe Acrobat Pro. You do have to pay for it but it's not expensive and they do offer an academic and 'not-for-profit' discount.

There's a free trial available that you can download to see if you like it. So far I've had no issues with it and there are both 32/64-bit editions available.

Answer (score 0):

Try :

- [Master PDF editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/) (free for non-commercial use).
- [PDF Import Extension of OpenOffice](http://extensions.services.openoffice.org/project/pdfimport) (even if not maintained).

Answer (score 0):

[Scribus 1.5](https://www.scribus.net/) will allow you to import and edit multi-page PDF's. It's open source.

To import just open a PDF file and export to PDF again after you have finished.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to do things like watermarking/stamping pages for this I would normally use [pdftk Server](https://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/).

- Linux **Yes** & Windows/OS-X/Source
- Gratis **Yes** *unless you need commercial support or wish to redistribute*
- Watermark all pages the same **[Yes](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-background)** create a single page pdf and use the `background` command to have it used as a watermark on every page, e.g. `pdftk in.pdf background back.pdf output out.pdf` will use *the first page of* back.pdf as a watermark for every page.
- Watermark pages differently **[Yes](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-man-page/#dest-op-multibackground)** create a multi page pdf and use the `multibackground` command to have the first page used as a watermark on the first page, etc, e.g. `pdftk in.pdf multibackground back.pdf output out.pdf` will use *the first page of* back.pdf as a watermark for the first page *the last page of back.pdf is used for any extra pages of in.pdf*.
- Stamp pages **Yes** the same as above but using the stamp/multistamp commands.
- You can also add/insert/remove/reorder/rotate pages.

The pages that you wish to add or overlay can be generated with any pdf creator such as LibreOffice or InkScape.