# PDF editor for Linux

Tags: linux, pdf-editor

I am looking for a good PDF editor similar to [Foxit Phantom](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/) for Linux. Unfortunately [Foxit Phantom](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-editor/)  is for Windows only and I couldn't install it with Wine.

What I need is an option to modify/delete some part of PDF (text/image) and save it as PDF format.

I don't care if it is free or paid program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Master PDF Editor](https://code-industry.net/free-pdf-editor/) is a very capable PDF editor. It can do what you ask and much more. The Linux version is free for non commercial use.

Master PDF Editor provides you advanced functions for working with PDF format:

• Create new PDF or edit existing ones.

• Add and/or edit bookmarks in PDF files.

• Fast and simple PDF forms fill out.

• Changing font attributes (size, family, color etc).

• Encrypt and/or protect PDF files using 128 bit encryption.

• Convert XPS files into PDF.

• JavaScript support.

• Dynamic XFA form support.

• Validation Forms and Calculate Values.

• Add PDF controls (like buttons, checkboxes, lists, etc.) into your PDFs.

• Import/export PDF pages into common graphical formats including BMP, 
JPG, PNG, and TIFF.

• Signing PDF documents with digital signature, signatures creation and validation.

• Free PDF Editor on Linux ( for non-commercial use)

[image]

[image]

Comment: very nice program, tnx!