# software for editing pdf

Tags: windows, linux, open-source

I need to edit a report generated by a software. I am looking for a software that can modify the pdf report so that I can add some few elements and contents to it.

can you recommend a software that can perform this task possibly also cross platform (windows, linux)

Comment: Is your question not answered by https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/35900/pdf-editor-for-linux and https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/26788/simple-free-pdf-editor-for-windows ?

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, master pdf editor seems to suite my needs

Answer (score 0):

I am using [pdfchef](https://www.pdfchef.com/)

> **PDF software for smooth work across devices**
> PDFChef is there for you anytime, no matter where you’re working. Turn your paper-based documents into PDFs with the PDFChef mobile scanner. Read, edit, convert, merge, and sign your files in the desktop PDF program. Open PDFChef online to work with PDFs right in your browser. Access files in the cloud storage from any device. Join the PDFChef family and stay on top of your files at home, at the office, and on the move.

Its available for Apple and Windows. And not too pricey.

I am not associated with them.